# Accessing User data in WebAPI from Context/Cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

**Update:**

I have changed my code to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(_model.UserName, true);`. I do have 2 Web.config files, 1 for MVC and the other for WebAPI. In MVC config, I define the

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Both applications are on the same domain.

---

**Update:** Should we even be using cookies in WebAPI?

---

Currently, I have a MVC project which uses forms authentication and a WebAPI project. The problem is that I can't get the user associated with the request in the WebAPI project. I thought this would be possible or perhaps the implementation is wrong?

NB: I put the cookie code in the WebAPI controller method as a test, it's not where it should be.

**MVC - handles login request, create auth ticket.**

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel _model, string _returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(_model.UserName, _model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(_model.UserName, true, 15);
            string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            // set redirect
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(_model);
}
```

**WebAPI - handles update request**

```
[AcceptVerbs("PUT")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateInfo(int _id, ExampleModel _model)
{
    try
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            string encTicket = authCookie.Value;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encTicket))
            {
                // decrypt the ticket if possible.
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encTicket);

                var userData = ticket.UserData;
            }
        }

        // do update
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        m_logger.Error(err);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: So the cookie is null?

Comment: Yes, the cookie is null.

Comment: Are the 2 sites on the same domain?

Comment: Both sites are on the same domain.

Comment: You're testing this locally? Whats the full URL to your Login action and whats the full url to the UpdateInfo action?

Comment: If you use fiddler, can you actually see the cookie being sent to the web api request?

Comment: In the `ApiController`, what is the value of your `User.Identity.Name` property? Is it an empty string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why mess with creating the forms authentication ticket manually? Why can't you just do this?

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(_model.UserName, _model.Password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(_model.UserName, true);

    // set redirect
}
```

To control the timeout, you can set that in your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms timeout="15" />
</authentication>
```

If you do this, you should not have to check the cookie to get the user's name. It should automatically be set on your controller's `User.Identity.Name` property. This works for both MVC `Controller`s and `ApiController`s.

Also, if you have your MVC application and your WebAPI application hosted on different nodes in your web server (or on different servers), both the MVC project and the WebAPI project must have the same `machineKey` in their web.config files. They also must be on the same domain, but if they are separate applications with separate web.config files, they must have the same `machineKey` values (`decryption`, `decryptionKey`, `validation`, and `validationKey`). Those are the values needed to validate, encrypt, and decrypt the .ASPXAUTH cookie.

> Should we even be using cookies in WebAPI?

If you use the pattern above, you shouldn't have to manually get any cookies, at least for authentication / authorization. Cookies are part of the HTTP specification, along with methods, headers, response codes, etc. WebAPI has them in there for a reason. If you need them, use them. If you don't need them, don't use them.

What you should try to avoid is getting them by doing this:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["name"];
```

You can get to the cookies from an ApiController like so:

```
IEnumerable<CookieHeaderValue> cookies = this.Request.Headers.GetCookies("name");
if (cookies.Any())
{
    IEnumerable<CookieState> cookie = cookies.First().Cookie;
    if (cookie.Any())
    {
        string value = cookie.First().Value;
    }
}
```

**Update**

I always use this generation tool: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Just click the "Generate key" button, and then paste the resulting `<machineKey ../>` section somewhere under the `<system.web>` section of both web.config files.

**Update**

There can be security issues depending on who has access to view your web.config file. If you check it into your source control repository like this, any person who can access your source code can see the validation and encryption keys.

What I do is a bit convoluted, but it keeps these strings secured. You can instead store the `validationKey` and `encryptionKey` values in `appSettings`, and then encrypt the `appSettings` sections of your config files (using something like [CloudConfigCrypto](https://github.com/danludwig/CloudConfigCrypto)). This means those values cannot be read out by anyone who does not have access to your encryption certificate's private key. You can then use the `Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager` class to change the `machineKey` values at runtime, during `Application_Start`. More details about this are out of scope for this question though.

Another option would be to just keep these out of source control, but then you have to manually update the web.config each time you deploy.

Comment: I updated my code to reflect what you suggest (see OP) but `User.Identity.Name` remains empty. You say that both web configs should have the same machinekey values, but neither of the config files contain this element. How do I go about generating this?

Comment: I updated my answer. There are a few tools out there, just google "generate machineKey". The resulting `<machineKey>` element belongs under `<system.web>`, so as a sibling of your `<authentication>` element.

Comment: Adding the machine key to both web configs work, I now have access to User.Identity with the expected data populated. Thanks! Although, how much of a concern is it to store the validation key as a long string like that? Are there any security issues?

Comment: I updated my answer. Security can be an issue depending on who you want to have access to your encryption and validation keys. You can instead encrypt those as appSettings values, then at runtime, read them out and update the web.config programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to use form authentication together with Web API and the MVC application by using the [`WebSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) class in the `WebMatrix.WebData` namespace. It provides very simple access to most often used operations such as create user accounts, log users in and out, reset or change passwords. And you don't have to deal with the session cookie yourself.

I used it in a setup similar to yours where we had to use Forms Authentication for both the Web API and the MVC application.

**API Examples**

Login:

```
if(WebSecurity.Login(username, password))
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Invalid credentials");
}
else
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Register:

```
if(WebSecurity.UserExists(username))
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(
        HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Username already exists");
}

WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password, data);

HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(
    HttpStatusCode.Created, yourUserObject);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(
        Url.Link("DefaultApi",
            new { controller = "users", id = WebSecurity.GetUserId(username) }));
return response;
```

The same calls work for the MVC application.